# Auto cleanup of inactive sessions in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I am wondering if there is any method I can set the inactive sessions to be automatically cleaned up after a period of time. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a way to set it directly because some inactive sessions may be active again after a period of time. However, you can use a user-defined function to call a scheduled job. An exaple is shown following:

```
def closeNotActiveSessions() {
    gap = 43200000 \\ 12:00:00.000
    sessionIds = exec sessionId from pnodeRun(getSessionMemorytStat) where now() - lastActiveTime > gap
    closeSessions(sessionIds)
}
scheduleJob(jobId = `daily, jobDesc = "Daily Job 1", jobFunc = closeNotActiveSessions, scheduleTime = 10:00m, startDate = 2022.01.01, endDate = 2022.12.31, frequency = 'D')
```